# c# keypress listening in background at console application

Tags: c#, events, delegates, c#-2.0, console-application

Hello all

I am working with .Net 2 at console application.

I have a method that do a long job. it name is:

`public void DO(){....}`

i want when key-press to stop the job.

how i do it elegant?

with event?

thanks for your help

Comment: What does `DO()` do? Is it doing transactions with a database? Is there a `while` loop inside?

Answer (score 2):

One of the solution can be simply run `DO(..)` in another thread, and listen for the key press on main thread `Console.ReadLine()` or any other overload. At the moment you get a key, signal to `DO(...)` method's thread to stop.

**EDIT**

Simple, very basic example (I see you're talking about C# 2.0) by using `volatile bool` variable can find here:

[Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: thank you for your answer, i think it should work, but i want to find a simpler solution. i think with delegates and events i easily do that task.

Comment: if you want to have a run long running process and whant to be able to be sure to cancel in moment user needs that, there no other option that multithreading. Having events will not help you a lot, if you're application main thread is beasy in heavy calculations.

Comment: i use with timer events. it work fine :)
but thank you for your explanation

Comment: @Tal: I suppose you used System.Timers.Timer, it runs on another thread.

Comment: yes, i use System.Timers.
if it work on another thread it fine :)
if i don't do it myself it o.k. for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Like Tigran said, just use a Thread.
Using events freezes the application till the next event is listened.

```
private static bool abortthread = false;

public static void main()
{
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(DO)).Start();
    Console.ReadLine();
    abortthread = true;
}

private static DO()
{
    while(true)
    {
      if(abortthread)
      return;
    }
}
```